# Pass custom object to another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a class

```
class Message
{
    public String message, sender;
    public Message (String msg, String from)
    {
        // check here that msg and from are not null. If so, use a default value or throw an NullPointerException
        message = msg;
        sender = from;
    }
    // Just a utility method for printing out the Message to System.out
    public String toString () { return sender+":"+message; }
}
```

I am defining in main activity

```
Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>> table = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>>();
```

I want to pass this table variable to another fragment.How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Interface & have custom listeners.

[Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Can you give an example for my question ?

Comment: @TolgayToklar You can download official demo from the above link, I strongly suggest you to refer to official docs or google before you ask.

Comment: I think it's not for me,I want to send custom objecto fragment don't want to get data from fragment.

Comment: @TolgayToklar no that is exactly what you want, read the article and you will see how you communicate with fragments

Comment: I can't do it from documents.I need an example for my question. :(

Comment: @TolgayToklar A quick hint would be, change `public void onArticleSelected(int position);` to `public void onArticleSelected(Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>> table;`, under `interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener`. Try to put some effort, you will get some idea.

Comment: @VenomVendor Actually,I can pass the object to fragment.But I can't use size() function in fragment.Can you review my code ? I am getting nullpointer exception.